# MacBook Pro: Erratic Trackpad behavior when an external 3.5" drive is connected

Tags: mac, hard-drive, external-disk, trackpad

When I plug my external 3.5" hard drive into my 13" 2016 MacBook Pro, the Trackpad becomes very erratic and difficult to use. The drive is housed in a powered enclosure (brand Integral). Other external drives don't do this (2.5" without external power). Otherwise the MacBook functions normally, Bluetooth mouse works fine, the keyboard works fine.

I suspect this has something to do with the drive being powered externally. What could be causing this? And is it dangerous for the computer (or me)?

Edit: the drive won't mount when the MacBook is connected to external power. If I plug in the MacBook, the drive immediately ejects.

Comment: What is the make and model of your MacBook Pro?

Comment: Hi, it's a 13-inch 2016.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ask different. Does this problem persist when booted into safe mode (booting whole holding down the `shift` key)?

Comment: not sure about safe mode, i'll try it at next reboot